# Python urllib2 library

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2

I copied an example whcich use this library but when i get to the line `import urllib2`
it gives me an error : No module named 'urllib2'.
I searched for a download of the library but couldnt found.
Anyone can help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Why version of Python?

Answer (score 3):

It's most probable that you are using Python 3.

With Python versions > 3, those relevant modules are structured like [this](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#urllib-package):

```
Current Name      Replacement Name
urllib2           urllib.request, urllib.error
urlparse          urllib.parse
urllib            urllib.parse, urllib.request, urllib.error [6]
robotparser       urllib.robotparser
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Python 3. In Python 3, urllib2 is renamed to urllib.

More info [Python urllib](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html)